# Conditionally load public and admin code with AJAX working on both sides on WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to conditionally load my front-end and admin area code in WordPress plugin, so the file and class that creates admin area will on load on admin side and file and class that is needed to be run on front-end will run only on front-end and won't touch anything on admin area.

I tried to use `is_admin()` conditional:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'public/class-public.php');
    $this->Public = new Public();
} else {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'admin/class-admin.php');
    $this->Admin = new Admin();
}
```

code loading was fine, but AJAX was not working on public side, as AJAX requests bound to either `wp_ajax_` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_` actions are executed in the WP Admin context. So I decided to create my own `isAdmin()` function:

```
public static function isAdmin() {
    $currentUrl = set_url_scheme(
        sprintf(
            'http://%s%s',
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
        )
    );
    $adminUrl = strtolower(admin_url());
    $referrer  = strtolower(wp_get_referer());

    if (strpos($currentUrl, $adminUrl) === 0) {
        if (strpos($referrer, $adminUrl) === 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (function_exists('wp_doing_ajax')) {
                return !wp_doing_ajax();
            } else {
                return !(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (!defined('REST_REQUEST') || !REST_REQUEST) {
            return false;
        }
        return (isset($_REQUEST['context']) && $_REQUEST['context'] === 'edit');
    }
}
```

code loading was still fine, but now AJAX was working on the public side and not working on the admin side.

So, how can I prevent loading public code on admin area code and vice versa with AJAX working on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by also checking for public interface. I created new function `isPublic()` to check if it is public. So here is my final code:

```
if ($this->isPublic()) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'public/class-public.php');
    $this->Public = new Public();
} elseif ($this->isAdmin()) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'admin/class-admin.php');
    $this->Admin = new Admin();
}
```

and here are helper `isPublic()` and `isAdmin()` functions:

```
public static function isAdmin() {
    if (function_exists('is_admin') && is_admin()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static function isPublic() {
    if (function_exists('is_admin') && is_admin()) {
        if (function_exists('wp_doing_ajax') && wp_doing_ajax()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin') !== false) {
            if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin-ajax.php') !== false) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```